# 'Build input file cannot be found' Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.0

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11, xcode10, xcode12

I am getting the following error when building in Xcode 10.0 with swift 4.2:

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found

Comment: The same issue, Xcode  gives that error for Info.plist for appnameUITests and appnameTests.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71027967/5175709). Tldr the **report navigator** may not give all information you need. So it might be a good idea to look into the **issue navigator**...

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Moving the folders around the inspector can cause the error "Build input file cannot be found"

**SWIFT 5**

In Swift 5, the error came up but the identity showed no errors.

- Go under build settings and select packaging.
- Delete the current paths for Debug and Release and enter your new path where the info.plist is kept.

For example [APPROJECTNAME]/[THEINFOPLISTFOLDER]/info.plist
In the screenshot below, the path is API-client/Resources/info.plist

[image]

**SWIFT 4**

To fix it, go to the general tab and under identity reselect the info.plist that you like

[image]

[image]

Comment: As there was no option for me to Choose Info.plist file, I just clicked on General and some random tabs without doing anything then Clean & Build the project and it worked. :)

Comment: I just updated the info.plist path in the build settings

Comment: Clearing the info.plist path from "Build Settings" and setting it again worked for me

Comment: Cleaning with ⇧⌘K ( Shift + Command + K )  and 'cd ios && pod install' did the trick (developing with React Native)

Comment: I have the same issue with Xcode 12.5.1 any solution for this?

Answer (score 69):

**Build input file cannot be found**

**How To fix This issue :**

1. Go in the project-navigator, select your project
2. Select Build Phases tab
3. In Compile Sources section, check for the file(s) that Xcode is demanding of
4. Notice that the file(s) have the wrong path, and delete them by clicking on the minus icon
5. Re-add the file(s) by clicking the plus icon and search in the project.
6. Product > Clean Build Folder
7. Build

Comment: Its amazing that the `Compile Sources` doesn't have a filter/search ability

Comment: This worked for me. The swift files can be found in "Compile Sources" (step 3 of the answer) - and if you are having trouble with a storyboard file, they can be found under "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: What if the file is in a swift package, for which there is no project file?

Comment: This one works for me, thanks. I see a lot of core data used files in `Compile Sources` section.

Answer (score 26):

A most common error when you move **Info.plist** in another folder.
To fix this error you can select the Info.plist and choose **Relative to Project** from file inspector.

[image]

Next step, go to **Build settings** and search for **info.plist** and fix the file path.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

I got this issue after resolving the conflicts in project.pbxproj.

Step 1: Removing the "Build input files cannot be found" files from BuildPhases -> Copy Bundle resources and adding them back worked for me.

If the above Step 1 doesn't work, search for "Recovered References" folder in your project structure and remove the files that are causing this issue and repeat Step 1

Comment: removing the recovered references folder was the ticket. it contained missing references to the files and that was where the error was coming from

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with a missing view controller file that couldn't be found after cloning a project in a new folder. I deleted the view controller but the compiler continue asking for a file in a path that doesn't exist anymore.

I solved the problem as follows:

- Select the project target in the Project-navigator,
- Go to Build Phases tab
- In Compile Sources section, check for the file that the compiler is asking for. You can filter by the name at the top right of the screen.
- The deleted file is still on the list with a wrong path, delete it by clicking on the minus icon. You have to do it for all the target you may have.
- In the case that you still use the file, add it on a new path by clicking the plus icon.
- Clean Build Folder in the Product Menu.

It should work now :D

(Objective-C Project  / Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001))

Comment: I update the info: Not only in Compile Sources, you can do it in bundle resources or any other section to solve this kind of issue

Answer (score 11):

For build file missing i.e. info.Plist :
Under Project navigator,
    select(click) Project name and icon,

In middle pane, click target
    click blue General tab on top
    click / Targets
    click [Choose info.plist File] button
        in pop-up window, select the info.Plist file

Answer (score 7):

This works if you get the 'Build input file cannot be found error message' and also have files that are red in the inspector:

1. Open your project folder in Finder
2. Make a copy of the affected files onto your Desktop
3. Delete the affected files in Xcode and then close Xcode
4. Re-Open Xcode and drag your copied files into your Xcode project

This worked for me. Before I got the error message I was re-organising files in the file inspector which gave me that error message and made the files I was moving around turn red. Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 6):

For me something totally different worked:

Go to **Target>Build Settings>Architectures**

[My valid architectures before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLJVR.png) **arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s** (Defaults)

[Changed it to:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb1Fs.png) **armv7 i386 arm64 armv7s**

Answer (score 6):

I tried going to `Compile Sources` in the `Build Phases` tab and deleting and re-adding the selected file (and cleaning and rebuilding)but it didn't work :( Instead, this following answer worked for me if you get the 'Build input file cannot be found' error message:

1. Delete the affected files in Xcode (I right-clicked->Delete'd in the Navigator)
2. Re-add the affected file (mine was `.mlmodel`) and I selected "Copy items if needed" under Destination.
3. `Cmd-shift-k` to clean and then `Cmd-b` to build 
   and voila! The file was recognized and error gone!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Deleting and re-adding files helped me

Answer (score 6):

For me this worked:

Click the app name under `TARGETS`

```
Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File
```

There change the file location of the Info.plist File to the new location.

```
DemoApp/Info.plist to DemoApp/Assets/Info.plist
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when I moved my Info.plist into a folder.

When I took Info.plist out of the folder, I no longer got an error.

Comment: Happened to me upon moving the Info.plist also

Answer (score 5):

Change the build setting to legacy

1. First, open your project in XCode by double-clicking on `ios/<YourApp.xcodeproj>`
2. Then go to *File > Project Settings...*
3. Change the Build System to Legacy Build System in Per-User Project Settings:

[image]

Comment: I try that but i get other error `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Comment: this only hides the issue and will inevitably backfire when the legacy build system is no longer supported

Answer (score 5):

Select general tab and under identity select the info.plist you want for your development

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got this error when I renamed a ViewController name using **Refactor**. The view controller name occurrences were changed but the real file not.

I tried to do what @ajji said but it didn't work. So I changed the name of the real file. After that all worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

If your file(s) - that couldn't find - icon color is pale. And you right click on it and "Show in Finder" does not open Finder. It means your file name is not same as what you see in the Navigator. 
[image: How icons of your files show in normal and pale mode]

to Solve it, go to where your file exist, and change its name to be same as what you see in the Navigator.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same issue while building my xcode project - "Build input file cannot be found:"
Cause: I renamed my entire project but not the build setting.
Solution: In my project's *build setting--> Packaging*, I updated the path of the info.plist file. Now working fine.

Comment: AMAZING. I renamed my project and for whatever reason doing a global search this was missed.

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails:

1. In Xcode. Remove references of files in question from your project.
2. Open your project.pbxproj file as a file in Xcode. This is in .xcodeproj
3. Delete all lines containing the name of said files. Save.
4. Back in Xcode. Re-add files to your project in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the file wasn't at the right path, Xcode was expecting to find the input file at a path like `/Users/Malloc/Projects/MyProject/Info.plist` while in reality the file was located at a different path like `/Users/Malloc/Projects/MyProject/Subfolder/Info.plist`.

A quick fix to this is to simply right click on the file then select `Show in Finder`, then drag the file to the correct path Xcode is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when i renamed a ViewController name using "Refactor". The view controller name occurrences were changed but an old reference was somewhere still existing.

> Deleting  **derived data** & **Clean build folder** worked for me.

Here's how to delete Derived data:

File>Workspace settings> Click arrow & remove all folders inside Derived Data.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was due to localization.
Here's how to fix it.
[How to localise a string inside the iOS info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736700/how-to-localise-a-string-inside-the-ios-info-plist-file)

Answer (score 2):

## Update for Projects w/ Swift Packages

### How did the errors happen?

I ran into this issue when I had imported Swift Packages into my project but later cleaned `DerivedData` to fix an unrelated app caching issue. My existing project was not a local Swift Package but an iOS app project.

Note that we can still encounter the same issue in local Swift Package projects.

### What is the reason for the errors?

Swift Packages are checked out into `DerivedData` and are not referenced from the `ModuleCache.noindex` subfolder. Thus, cleaning the app's folder in `DerivedData` or `DerivedData` itself breaks dependency resolution within Xcode for Swift Packages.

This is a misleading build error since there may be nothing wrong with the app code you've written or your dependency resolution graph. The only thing required is to refresh the dependencies.

### How can I resolve the build errors?

Xcode now has nice options within the IDE itself to resolve Swift Packages. These options trigger a new checkout into `DerivedData`:

[image]

We can use three options, as shown in the image above depending on our use case:

1. <kbd>Reset Package Caches</kbd>: Trigger a re-install of your existing Package dependencies w/ same versions.
2. <kbd>Resolve Package Versions</kbd>: Use this option for updating Package checkouts when fixing Package Versions for cross-compatibility (in Project Settings).
3. <kbd>Update to Latest Package Versions</kbd>: Use this to update all Swift Package dependencies to the latest versions. This option may be a local breaking change if the API changes.

**NOTE**: Apple's documentation [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/adding_package_dependencies_to_your_app) to use Xcode for dependency resolution when working with Xcode projects excluding CLTs.

### Other solutions

1. We can also fix the error by restarting Xcode, but I find this step breaks my workflow and is tedious.
2. If we are running from the command line (local Swift Package executable), we can stick with a `swift build` variant without jumping to Xcode at all ([Source](https://swift.org/package-manager/#example-usage)). `swift build` doesn't work as easily out of the box in other projects, however.
3. Use `xcodebuild`:

   ```
   xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies
   ```

I prefer staying in Xcode for simplicity but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

- Goto Project Navigator.
- Click on project.
- Click on Targets.
- Goto Build Settings.
- Search Prefix.pch.
- Change the location of this file (input the updated location).

This will resolve the issue as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with swift files. Select files that are not recognised and Delete with `Remove Reference` option. Right click in the folder and Add files again.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, if you **Refactor** your existing **ViewController** files or any other files using  **right-click -> Refactor option** within the ***Xcode workspace*** then on `compiling this error will come` since the File name is not changed in original place but reference is updated, so in that you need to also manually change the old file to new name.

Answer (score 1):

When I checked out the code first time from the Git I faced the same issue for few pod file. Updating the pod file solved my issue.

1. Open the project folder in the terminal window
2. Run 'pod update'
3. Clean the XCode and run.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to open the project in finder and drag/drop the appropriate files in the project folder

Answer (score 1):

Build input file cannot be found

How to fix this issue?

My Approach:

1. 1.From Project Navigator ->Files ->Add Files to Lowes ->In Finder View, check to which folder this lost referenced file is moved
   to    and check with your team members if anyone moved it for a reason.If it occurred by mistake
   then    follow below steps

   2.From Project navigator, directly tap on the file which is causing issue.This is the same file that XCode shows as not found in
   error    .So clearly this file has lost reference and we need to
   restore it    back

   3.The Swift bird folder icon appears in light red color which is an indication of lost reference

   4.Right click on it and Delete it

   5.Next from Project navigator -> Files ->Add Files to Lowes -> Finder View go to the folder where this referenced file is moved to
   and tap    on ADD button in popup window

   6.Now if you look at the Project Navigator this file swift bird icon appears in bright red , but you will also find an extra file
   with the    same name at the top of the Project Navigator

   7.Make sure you have this file in the right folder if not move it to right folder

   8.Now right click to delete the very top redundant file, here do not select " Move to Trash" option.Just select "Remove References" option

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Adjust the file path according to that provided in the Xcode Error**

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a missing SettingsController file.

I copied a file from projectA to projectB but forgot to tick `Copy items if needed`. Unbeknownst to me a couple of weeks later when I deleted projectA the SettingsController file in projectB got deleted along with it. Afterwards in projectB the error `Build input file cannot be found ... path/Folder/toSomeFile` was shown.

To fix it I closed Xcode, went to the main folder that it was in, opened the folder and right clicked on the **blue** Xcode icon with the extension `.xcodeproj`, then I choose `Show Package Contents`

[image]

From there I double clicked on the `project.pbxproj` icon

[image]

Once the `project.pbxproj` file was opened I pressed **command+f** and in the search field I entered the path part of the error `path/Folder/toSomeFile`

It took me to 1-2 lines of code that looked like this

[image]

Once I deleted those 1-2 lines, when I went back to the projectB and opened it the error was gone.

Just for a little more clarity the exact path of the error was `whogotgame_42/whogotgame/Controllers/SettingsController.swift`. So that is what I exactly entered in the `project.pbxproj` search field to get to those 1-2 lines that you see in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I put the Info.plist file inside a folder. Then when I extracted the file to public view, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(INFOSTRINGS_PATH)

It's Bundle file path. Specifies the file that contains the bundle’s localized strings file.