# Xcode simulator: "/.app is not a valid path to an executable file"

Tags: xcode, simulator

Similar to [Executable Not Found. xxx.app is not a valid path to an executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934488/executable-not-found-xxx-app-is-not-a-valid-path-to-an-executable-file), but the **.app in the dialog message does not have a filename**, there must be an empty setting which is expected to be the project name, so I even cannot copy my .app to that location.

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing same issue.I tried lots of way to resolved it.did you resolve it?