# Executable Path is a Directory issue when run the app in iOS xcode 14

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode14

I am facing the above issue. I have checked the mention path and found that It is not a directory, It is a valid executable path still facing the same issue.

Details are below:

`````
Executable Path is a Directory
Domain: DVTMachOErrorDomain
Code: 5
Recovery Suggestion: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project name-hjamepccgssuuxegmglcegpnsvkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/projectname.app is not a valid path to an executable file.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-06-12 12:59:16 +0000";
}
--````
`````

Comment: I think you need to remove xcode derivedData and building it again. If not fixed check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934488/executable-not-found-xxx-app-is-not-a-valid-path-to-an-executable-file)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding x86_64 to VALID_ARCHS. Build Setting search "VALID_ARCHS",check the x86_64 is there or not, add and run.It worked with me