# React Native - Running iOS in XCode - Build input file cannot be found

Tags: ios, react-native

Build input file cannot be found: 'App/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/ExpoModulesProvider.swift'. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435202/build-input-file-cannot-be-found-swift-4-2-xcode-10-0) question?

Comment: I think I need to do a pod install but am getting a new error with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550687/pod-install-fails-due-to-glog

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem when building prod variant. I changed to dev variant and it worked.