# Pod Install Fails Due to Glog

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following error when trying to run

```
pod install
```

[!] Error installing glog
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/glog.git /var/folders/b4/0h5z4ll13k30c3dq47jlxqph0000gn/T/d20220320-1344-ulqfrn --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v0.3.5

Cloning into '/var/folders/b4/0h5z4ll13k30c3dq47jlxqph0000gn/T/d20220320-1344-ulqfrn'...
fatal: remote error:
The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

change /Applications/Xcode.app to your Xcode's app path.

Comment: Still having the same issue

Comment: Could you please show me a log of the bug. a screenshot will do

Comment: Random question, are you using some kind of external disk?

Comment: also, try installing cocoapods via homebrew

1. install homebrew: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
2. brew install cocoapods
3. sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app (or the correct path of your Xcode)
4.pod install
(if brew is already installed, uninstall cocoapods then reinstall)

Comment: same error as before

Answer (score 0):

Github released a new security update on March 15, 2022 as it is described [in the provided link of the error message](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/).

> March 15, 2022    Changes made permanent.
>
> We’ll permanently stop accepting DSA keys. RSA keys uploaded after the cut-off point above will work only with SHA-2 signatures (but again, RSA keys uploaded before this date will continue to work with SHA-1). The deprecated MACs, ciphers, and unencrypted Git protocol will be permanently disabled.

Check your `package-lock.json` and replace any occurrence of `git://github.com` with `https://github.com`.

If this doesn't work, you could try changing your config via the command line by executing the following command.

```sh
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Then, execute `pod install` again.

Comment: There were no git://github.com in the package-lock.json and the config change didn't work.