# Problem after upgrading to xcode 10 - file not found

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I upgraded my Xcode to version 10 and then find I cannot build.
But working fine in Xcode 9. I also see this link: [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 10: Build input file cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found) but solution not work.

I'm getting this error:
 [image]

Comment: can you try to delete and add this file again.

Comment: yes i did but not working.