# why I got error Build input file cannot be found when I remove the file from my download folder?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I have `GoogleService-info.plist` file in my project file of my app. The way I copy that file to my project is like this

I download the `GoogleService-info.plist` from Firebase site to my download folder on my Mac. and then I copy by dragging that file from download folder to Xcode by using this

[image]

and my problem is ....

when I delete the `GoogleService-info.plist` from the download folder on my mac, it will cause error on my Xcode project, the file is also dissappear from my project like this

[image]

> Build input file cannot be found:
>   '/Users/dev.adsapps/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist'

what went wrong in here ?

I have tried to search the answer like in this thread [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 10: Build input file cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found) but it seems the problem is little bit different

do I have the wrong way when copying the file to my project ?

I am using Xcode 10.

Comment: First download the plist file to your download map (which is done automatically), then copy the file to your apps main folder, then drag and drop it in Xcode. If you drag and drop directly from your download map to Xcode the reference is to the file in your download map, so when you delete it, the file will show red in Xcode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for **Added folder** options while adding `GoogleService-Info.plist`. You should select the first radio button **Create groups** instead of **Create folder references** and it will not be removed when you remove it from the other location, for now you are just referencing the item while adding it to the workspace.

Hope it helps.