# Receiving a build error related to storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I downloaded some Xcode projects from the Stanford University website.
But when I run them, I get the following two errors:

:-1: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/myUserName/Documents/Stanford IOS/Lectures Swift Code/EmojiArt L13/EmojiArt/Supporting Files/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard':-1: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/myUserName/Documents/Stanford IOS/Lectures Swift Code/EmojiArt L13/EmojiArt/Supporting Files/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard'

:-1: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/myUserName/Documents/Stanford IOS/Lectures Swift Code/EmojiArt L13/EmojiArt/Supporting Files/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard'

Here is the link to the project:

EmojiArtL12:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1reg6-ZhLPIubmNO6aMDoTni-G728H0b0

I tried looking for answers on this board but couldn't find any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 10: Build input file cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the 2 links in the error message, you will find the 2 files LaunchScreen.storyboard.xml -> change their file name to LaunchScreen.storyboard then it should build correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, qtngo is right. I'm traditionally a Windows user so make sure you're doing this properly. Check that the file extension has indeed been changed by right clicking the file and selecting 'Get Info'. If you see something like LaunchScreen.storyboard.storyboard, you need to correct this.

Comment: In addition to the answer by qtngo and comment above by marvatron, click on main.storyboard and launchscreen.storyboard then on right side under Identity and type select location equal to "relative to group".