# I have an error while changing app name Xcode

Tags: xcode

https://zeddios.tistory.com/286

I have followed this web site to change my project's name

The Original name is HM 10 Serial and TOUCHE and I want to union that to CANTUS.

But I have failed to change, so I tried to renamed it to the original name.

But when I start Xcode again, there is only

[What screen shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTMwK.jpg)

I don't know how to fix it....

and I have no back up file so I have to fix it.

What is this problem and how can I solve this?

I'm so so Desperate, So please any give me any possible idea.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ added @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

[Problem is getting better and is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhjmW.jpg)

now I have a different problem.

```
Build input files cannot be found: 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/UIColor.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/OperateViewController.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/PreferencesTableViewController.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/ScannerViewController.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/GraphViewController.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/SpeedButton.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/AppDelegate.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/BluetoothSerial.swift', 
'/Users/moongyeonguk/Downloads/TOUCH4s_charts_cracked_editing/TOUCHE/InitViewController.swift'
```

Comment: I have found there is some files that I didn't change its name.  I changed it. and there is no error. but same screen.

Comment: when I try to compile this file
Cannot compile "Podfile" without a run destination.
Select a run destination to perform this action.

Comment: I use this open source project https://github.com/appculture/xcode-project-renamer to change my xcode project names. I don't know how to fix your project back to normal but I can suggest a few things. If your using cocoapods, you could try this from the command line within your project folder. `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`. You might need to create a new project and copy all your swift files over, I think you'll have to remake your storyboards though.

Comment: Based on the second comment you posted I would certainly try `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`. Do this in the same directory you podfile is in.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for answer. I think problem is get better. But there is a still problem ;( Thanks anyway

Comment: Whats the new problem you're getting?

Comment: @Jacob I edited my question. and I'm reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found
for solving problem

Comment: Try changing everything back to the original name of your project if you can. Every place where you changed it, change it back.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for your advice. I will do that after solve this problem. Thanks again

Comment: I'm saying that will solve your problem, and then you can use that open source project I mentioned to change the name to the one you want. Remember to keep trying `pod deintegrate` and pod install when your making changes to file names.

Comment: @Jacob Oh... I have tried that first and got another error since I reintegrate and install cocoa pod.