# Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/zhixiangtan/ilistening_chounouryoku_check_ios/CustomButton.swift'

Tags: ios, swift

I have an error when I build my project.I want to get rid of it.what should I do?

```
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/zhixiangtan/ilistening_chounouryoku_check_ios/CustomButton.swift'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 10: Build input file cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an invalid reference in your project. Try selecting the file in the project navigator on the left and pressing delete. Then, when prompted, choose *Remove Reference* rather than *Move to Trash*. 
When this is done, just open the project folder in finder and drag the file back to Xcode.