# "Build input files cannot be found" and "Build Failed" XCode

Tags: xcode

I just tried running my app on Xcode, and an error message appeared saying, "Build input files cannot be found", and at the very top, it says, "Build failed". I cleaned up the code and I tried running it again and I also tried re-installing cocoapods in the terminal, but the same thing happened again. So I know for sure that, that is the error that is causing the problem. How can I fix it?

Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 10: Build input file cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401856/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-10-build-input-file-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 1):

Last year question, but here u go

1. Click on the red missing file
2. Go to the **Show the File inspector** on the right side
3. Make sure to choose the right type, if you don't know yet please choose **Default**
4. Change the location from **Absolute Path** to **Relative to Group**
5. Click the document button, and select the file that XCode think is missing

Once I've done this, the red on the name file gone, and I can build my project again