# Xcode fails to build: "Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile"

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, xcode10

My Xcode has suddenly stopped building one of my ExpoKit projects with the following error, and it occurs immediately after starting a new build or archive:

```
Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile (missingTargetProductReference("656b109b8b9d9c79df3aa75da033c5f529fe2a87b7c65fea7a8f025b04a3b7ff"))
```

I feel like I've tried everything: clearing all (Xcode-related) caches and recloning the repo, and finally even reinstalling Xcode. I don't experience the same thing with other projects (or workspaces) and there has been no recent changes to the iOS-native code in this project. Right now I'm even considering reinstalling my MacBook.

```
System:
  OS: macOS 10.14.1
  CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
  Memory: 31.65 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.10.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
  Android SDK:
    Build Tools: 23.0.1, 23.0.2, 23.0.3, 25.0.0, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
    API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
  Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz => 0.57.1
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native: 0.55.4
  solidarity-react-native: 2.0.2
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708012/error-unable-to-resolve-build-file-xcbcore-buildfile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to re-eject the ExpoKit project (which essentially means regenerating the entire iOS-native part of the project).

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Legacy build system in Workspace settings helped me