# Unable to Resolve Build File: Reference to Missing Target with GUID

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode12

I recently forked an iOS library on GitHub to add support to it for the Swift Package Manager. Here's the repository: https://github.com/skelpo/mapbox-gl-native-ios

When I add it to a completely new iOS app and try to build it, I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile (The workspace has a reference to a missing target with GUID 'PACKAGE-TARGET:Mapbox')
```

I've found posts for similar errors, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708012/error-unable-to-resolve-build-file-xcbcore-buildfile), but the reason for the build file failing to resolve is different.

I have tried the usual cleaning the build folder, deleting derived data, and restarting Xcode, but that hasn't helped.

What is the reason for this specific resolution failure, and how would I fix it?

Comment: This seems to be a common issue with Xcode 12. I have the same error with another SPM issue.

Comment: Were you able to get this figured out? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: @Kyle I got it fixed, but I can't say for sure what did it. I could have either been an Xcode update or fixing the source for a binary framework, but I don't really know. I wish I did.

Comment: My two errors were related to a test target that was dependent nf two.other test targets. I commented out that testTarget, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem after upgrading to Xcode 12 recently, and found a fix for my case.

A major hint that led to the solution came from [Aaron's May 3, 2019 answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708012/error-unable-to-resolve-build-file-xcbcore-buildfile).

What fixed it for me was to select the root of the Xcode project, and change the Project Format from "Xcode 11.0-compatible" to "XCode 12.0-compatible".